# TypeScript + mongoose object in array remove

Tags: node.js, typescript, interface, mongoose

I am having some difficulty with the removal of the object from the array by its _id /

**USchema.ts**

```
export interface IPayments {
value: string;
name: string;
}

export interface IUser {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    payments: Array<IPayments>;
}
var User = new Schema({    
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    payments: [{
        value: { type: String},
        name: { type: String}
    }]

export interface UserDocument extends IUser, mongoose.Document {
   _id: string;
}

export var userSchema = User;
export let userModel: mongoose.Model<UserDocument> = mongoose.model<UserDocument>('User', userSchema);
```

**Main.ts**

```
//delete elem from array "payments".
let payment_id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.payment);
let user = userModel.findOne({'_id': uid}).exec();
    user.then((user)=>{
        user.paymens.remove(payment_id);
        user.save();
     });
```

Delete work fine, but TypeScript says

> Property 'remove' does not exist on type IPayments

i try to add this "property" to interface, but still nothings

Comment: How did you add it? It should be a function

Comment: `remove?:( id:any):void;`

But is it really needed and typescript does not understand that this is part of the mongoose? )

Comment: try adding it this way `remove( id:any):void;` that has to work

Comment: still same errors ((

Comment: That is imposible. If you define `remove` in the interface the way I said you will never get this error again `Property 'remove' does not exist on type IPayments`. Are you sure you are not using any other interface with the same name? How did you define `Schema`?

Comment: `var User = new Schema({ ` - look at my post))

Comment: I know, I have two eyes to see it. But that is not the definition but the use. You are mixing javascript and Typescript, though it works you will get some problems if you still use `:` instead of `=` to give values. This `payments: [{
        value: { type: String},
        name: { type: String}
    }]` is probably giving the error because you don't seem to be using IPayments at all